# tensorflow seq2seq with multiple outputs

Tags: tensorflow

I just started to work on tensorflow not so long. I'm working on the seq2seq model and using seq2seq example code.

I want to modify seq2seq model code to get top-k outputs (k is 5 or 10) for the Reinforcement learning model, not to get top-1 output.

First, I think I should modify decoder part of the seq2seq somehow, but I don't know which part is to change.

Is there any references or codes for the problem?

Answer (score 1):

check out https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/654. There are some discussions on this, but no worked example yet.

Answer (score 1):

[`tf.contrib.seq2seq.BeamSearchDecoder`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/seq2seq/BeamSearchDecoder) would do the magic for you.